# Cannot get records with same month and year

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a list of objects with a property called `created`:

```
let objs = [
   { id: "1", created: "2019-02-12 00:00:00" },
   { id: "2", created: "2018-02-12 00:00:00" },
   { id: "3", created: "2017-02-12 00:00:00" },
   { id: "4", created: "2016-02-12 00:00:00" },
   { id: "5", created: "2015-02-12 00:00:00" }
]
```

I want return all the records which have as year 2019 and month: 02, so I did:

```
var curr_date = moment(moment(), "YYYY-MM-DD");
var in_month = objs.filter((item) => function () {
        return (moment(item.created, format).month() == curr_date.month() && 
                    moment(item.created, format).year() == curr_date.year())
});
```

the problem is that `in_month` always return the whole array, why? the expected output should be the record with id 1

Comment: You are using mixing arrow function `=>` and `function()`, this is wrong, just chose one of the two syntaxes. Moreover no need to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) for ISO 8601 (recognized by [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/)) input and for [current date and time](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/now/).

Comment: I would actually not bother with all that dynamic moment object creation, and rather check if the `created` property starts with `2019-02` using indexOf …

Comment: @04FS seems a good approach, could you elaborate an answer?

Comment: I agree with @04FS. That method reduces the use of a library file.

Comment: Your filter function would just `return item.created.indexOf('2019-02') === 0` Check for equality with 0, because only that means `2019-02` was found at the very start of the value.

Comment: @04FS if you will check for 2019-02 in the string, what will you do next month?

Comment: @Ariz that you obviously would keep _that_ part variable is so obvious IMHO, that I obviously did not explicitly mention it ;-) The important part here was to reduce complexity by not creating moment instances for the created value of every single item.

Comment: @04FS so you will decrease the complexity and come back every month to make the changes in code and redeploy?

Comment: @Ariz that you don’t put `'2019-02'` in there as _static text_, but assemble that one value using `curr_date.year()` and `curr_date.month()` or similar beforehand … again, so obvious IMHO, that it should not need mentioning.

Comment: IMHO it's better to mention everything. as you simply just can't combine the date and month in a string and compare as month in moment starts from 0 and aslo you will have to padStart the month with '0' having length 2, so it so much to be included in 'OBVIOUSLY'. :) over n out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just fixed it a little, problem was that your filter function evaluated the `function()` you passed instead of executing it, removing it works:

```
let objs = [
   { id: "1", created: "2019-02-12 00:00:00" },
   { id: "2", created: "2018-02-12 00:00:00" },
   { id: "3", created: "2017-02-12 00:00:00" },
   { id: "4", created: "2016-02-12 00:00:00" },
   { id: "5", created: "2015-02-12 00:00:00" }
]

let format = "YYYY-MM-DD"
var curr_date = moment(moment(), format);
var in_month = objs.filter(item => 
  moment(item.created, format).month() == curr_date.month() && 
  moment(item.created, format).year() == curr_date.year()
 );

console.log(in_month)
```

Comment: Since you yourself found the solution, I do not see the need for this question anymore.

Comment: I answered the question but I wasn't the one asking it :)

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt we are two different people :P

Comment: :( poor me sorry

Comment: @SilvioBiasiol seems works well Silvio thank you , oh and you are also italian like me :)

Comment: Ottimo, è stato un piacere :)

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt FYI It is perfectly acceptable to answer your own question on Stack Overflow. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Already answered, but still needed some fixes as creating multiple moment objects rather doing it only once.

```js
let objs = [
 { id: "1", created: "2019-02-12 00:00:00" },
 { id: "2", created: "2018-02-12 00:00:00" },
 { id: "3", created: "2017-02-12 00:00:00" },
 { id: "4", created: "2016-02-12 00:00:00" },
 { id: "5", created: "2015-02-12 00:00:00" }
]

var curr_date = moment(moment(), "YYYY-MM-DD");
var in_month = objs.filter(({ created }) => {
 let date = moment(created, "YYYY-MM-DD");
 return date.month() == curr_date.month() && date.year() == curr_date.year();
});
console.log(in_month)
```

Comment: Yeah, when i made my solution i also avoided making multiple moment objects.'

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```js
var in_month = objs.filter(item => 
  moment(item.created).format('YYYY') === '2019' &&
  moment(item.created).format('MM') === '02'
);
```

when you `console.log(in_month)` you will get the results :)

and btw the right format for the dates in your array is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`

Comment: Would not hard code the year and month if we want currect date month and year.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example.

Instead of filtering the collection i add the ids of the matching elements to an array.
Saving the ids to the objects we can use the same collection (let objs) again later.

```js
let objs = [
   { id: "1", created: "2019-02-12 00:00:00" },
   { id: "2", created: "2018-02-12 00:00:00" },
   { id: "3", created: "2017-02-12 00:00:00" },
   { id: "4", created: "2016-02-12 00:00:00" },
   { id: "5", created: "2015-02-12 00:00:00" }
]

var now = moment();
var targetYear = now.year();
var targetMonth = now.month(); //0 index

var hits = [];

objs.forEach(function (e) {
  var created = moment(e.created, "YYYY-MM-DD");
  if (created.year() == targetYear &&
  created.month() == targetMonth) {
    hits.push(e.id);
  }
});

console.log(hits);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```